# My laptop consumes 25 W of power when browsing on firefox(Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, battery, power-management

I bought a Dell Inspiron 3501 with 11th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 Processor

I cannot complain on the performance of the laptop but the battery life is extremely short.

Looking on the system monitor I am at most at 10%
([System monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXIQh.png) )for all 8 CPU

but the power statistic shows a consumption of 25W
([Power statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzXj0.png))

The previous data are taken during the laptop charge, when I was only using Firefox and no heavy web-site was running.

Moreover when I close the laptop I can feel that it is warm to the touch and leaving it overnight drains completely the battery

The battery life of this laptop is around 1.5 hours when in use.

Also doing a simple calculation of 42Wh battery capacity /25 W of power gives me around 1.5 hours so I confirmed the power measured by Ubuntu is correct

What do you think is the problem?

is it my machine, the model or some poorly configured software?

UPDATE:

the 25 W measurement was taken when the laptop was charging.

I followed the information
when the laptop is running on battery power the consumption with no application open is 7/8 W and the laptop feel warm to the touch.

[PowerTop Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpVKH.png)

[System monitor Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g02P.png)

To me 7/8 W seem still a lot of power for when the computer is idle. But I will update after a  normal use how the notebook behaves

the computer came with Windows preinstalled

I solved the issue for the power consuption when  the laptop is closed by following

Comment: Did your laptop come with Windows? Ubuntu may not be well configured to properly use sleep or hibernation, I would hope it's gotten better over the years... There are some guides at https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/lid-close-behavior-ubuntu-20-04/ It might also not be using power states properly on a newly released processor https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement

Comment: That your power statistic is *always* close to 25W does suggest that it is not using the lower power states supported by your processor. Modern processors can get pretty low (~5W) when idle... Can you try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270024/help-with-cpu-frequency-management

Comment: Have you run "poeertop"? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Firstly thank you for answering!

I followed your advice and I updated the question with the current results